# get database value on button click one by one

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

Well, I'm having a page where I wanna display the items stored in the database one by one. One by one means on click of a button the next item should come. (Items are the questions by the way in my case).

So I wrote the code for this. The problem I'm getting is that the loop is working only one time. I mean when the next button is clicked, I'm getting the next item displayed, but then I click Next again 'n nothing happens. Here's the code..

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oes_db");
$_SESSION['qno'] = 0;
if (!isset($_SESSION['qno']))
    $_SESSION['qno'] = 1;
else {
    if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
        $_SESSION['qno'] += 1;
    }
}
$select = "select * from oes_question where que_id='" . $_SESSION['qno'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $select);

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $qno = $row['que_id'];
        $question = $row['que_desc'];
        $op1 = $row['ans1'];
        $op2 = $row['ans2'];
        $op3 = $row['ans3'];
        $op4 = $row['ans4'];
        $answer = $row['true_ans'];
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="exam" method="post" action="que.php">
            <!--My Current page name is "exam.php" -->

<?php echo $question ?>  <br>

            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="op1"> <?php echo $op1; ?> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="op2"> <?php echo $op2; ?> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="op1"> <?php echo $op3; ?> <br>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="op1"> <?php echo $op4; ?> <br>
            <input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous">
            <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `$_SESSION['qno']` on every call of the page with `0` on line 3. First of all, this makes the variable set, which means `!isset($_SESSION['qno'])` will always equal `false`. So you always go into the `else` and add 1 to 0, when you have `$_POST['next']`, which means every time except for the first call.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['qno'])) {
    // first call (no session exists): get first question
    $_SESSION['qno'] = 1;
} else if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
    // click on next button: increase question ID by 1
    $_SESSION['qno']++;
}
// neither first init nor next button: page load with existing session
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your third line, always that you submit the form, your session is settees at 0 and when you sum += 1, always put 1.

Try

```
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oes_db");
if (!isset($_SESSION['qno']))
    $_SESSION['qno'] = 1; //or 0 if your item start at 0
else {
    if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
        $_SESSION['qno'] += 1;
    }
}
```